# Added framework appears in archive

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode8.2

I have added Airshipkit framework to my Xcode project. It has been integrated properly, but when I archive and extract IPA , it is showing added framework below IPA.
Please refer attached IPA.
Can someone tell me why it is appearing there?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we are using framework & pods in App then surely it added in Binary why because we embedded into.

There is no issue with that but make sure particular pod with bitcode flag, if they are not supported then uncheck bitcode dialogue box